# 1960's horror film with tentacled slug-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I vaguely recall a scary movie that I watched, as a kid, approx around 1970.

In the movie there were these giant (maybe 1 meter long) slug-like creatures, complete with a tentacle to better terrorize folks.

The only memorable scene is when two people were in a car and PLOP! one of the creatures landed on their windshield.

Any ideas what this movie could be?

Comment: I'm confused. Did you watch it around 1970 or 1960?

Comment: Was it in Black and White, Color, Technicolor?

Comment: Do you mean *Island of Terror*? There was a [similar question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52924/1970s-or-1980s-uk-scifi-movie-with-alien-slugs/53333#53333) on M&TV recently, and the movie does contain giant slugs with a tentacle (who at one point slide down a windshield).

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it sounds like a classic, I don't remember windshield scene but your description of the creatures sounds familiar. Technically, they're brains and spines with added tentacles but I can see a kid in the 70's seeing them as slug-like.

The wonderful, brain sucking creatures from the 1958 classic "Fiend Without a Face"

[image: A Brain Sucker is for Life, not just for Christmas]

[image: You've been hanging around the atomic plant again, haven't you!]

[image: I would have gone with jackets, pants and sturdy boots but I suppose you can fight brain sucking creatures in a towel.]

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [The 1988's remake of *The Blob*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRo5suPV4R0)?

I remembered there's a car scene where a couple gets eaten by a creature with tentacles in that movie. I always thought that movie is creepy.

Comment: Unlikely, as OP is asking about a movie he saw around 1970.

Answer (score -1):

[*Island of Terror*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060548/). 1966. Peter Cushing.

> An isolated remote island community is threatened by an attack by tentacled silicates which liquefy and digest bone and tissue.

Trailer:

Comment: Can you provide any more information that show's similarity betwen these two works?