# Old sci-fi movie where aliens dropped from trees and chased people

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was very young (1963-9) I saw this movie where aliens dropped from trees & chased people. Looking back aliens looked like canister type vacuums with long "necks". I'm thinking it was black & white. I do not remember anything else but it was very scary to me!

Answer (score 16):

I suspect this is ISLAND OF TERROR (1966). It fits your time frame and the monsters you are describing fit with the "silicates" of the film. They frequently drop on characters and resemble vacuum cleaners.

[image]

[image]

[Wiki summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_Terror)

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222141/movie-from-70s-or-earlier-about-a-genetically-created-organism-that-almost-took/222176#222176, also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174905/what-is-this-50s-or-60s-alien-invasion-movie/174917#174917 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129087/1960s-horror-film-with-tentacled-slug-like-creatures/193326#193326

Comment: Face hugger on steroids.